# Return type and argument type confusion in template

Tags: c++, templates

In this code, both return type and argument type of template is 'T' and  I have returned boolean. And in argument, integer/float is passed. But my code is running successfully. How is that possible?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
T SearchInArray(T x[], T element) {
   int j;
   for(j=0;j<5;j++){
       if(element==x[j])
       {return true;
       break;}
   }
   return false;
}

int main() {int i;
cout<<"Enter 5 integer numbers"<<endl;
int arr[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}
int n;
cout<<"Enter element to search: ";
cin>>n;
if(SearchInArray(arr,n))
cout<<"Element "<<n<<" is found"<<endl<<endl;
else
cout<<"Element "<<n<<" is not found"<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"Enter 5 float numbers"<<endl;
float arr1[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    cin>>arr1[i];
}
float n1;
cout<<"Enter element to search: ";
cin>>n1;
if(SearchInArray(arr1,n1))
cout<<"Element "<<n1<<" is found"<<endl<<endl;
else
cout<<"Element "<<n1<<" is not found"<<endl<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bool` is implicitly convertible to `int`, which in turn is convertible (implicitly) to a `float`, `double`, etc.

True is convertible to `1`, while false is convertible to `0`.

To prove that this is the case, change the `int` type of `n` and the `int[]` type of `arr` to `std::string` and `std::string[]`, respectively. For me, this is what the compiler shows:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Stack Overflow, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>C:\dev\Stack Overflow\Source.cpp(534,27): error C2451: a conditional expression of type 'T' is not valid
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=std::string
1>        ]
1>C:\dev\Stack Overflow\Source.cpp(534,19): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>Done building project "Stack Overflow.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The compiler is actually pretty smart, and figures out that `T` must be convertible to bool, and therefore it fails to compile, as `std::string` is not convertible to `bool`.

Comment: The clang-cl compiler is even smarter about your `std:string` example: it gives an error in the function body, as well, about the conversion **from** `bool`: *no viable conversion from returned value of type 'bool' to function return type*